# Why does reading files even slower using OpenMP?

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, openmp

I have a large file and I want to read several chunks of the file denoted by their offsets and sizes. I try to accelerate the reading yet only to find it almost 3 times slower.

Here is the demonstrating code:

```cpp
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <memory>

const uint32_t N = 400'000'000;

int main() {
    const char *const filename = "big_file.bin";

    int wfd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
    uint32_t *nums = new uint32_t[N];
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        nums[i] = i;
    }
    write(wfd, nums, sizeof(uint32_t) * N);
    close(wfd);


    int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);

    uint32_t n_shards = 16;
    uint32_t *offsets = new uint32_t[n_shards];
    uint32_t *sizes = new uint32_t[n_shards];
    uint32_t chunk_size = N / n_shards;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n_shards; ++i) {
        offsets[i] = i * chunk_size;
        sizes[i] = chunk_size;
    }
    sizes[n_shards - 1] = N - (n_shards - 1) * chunk_size;

    // only to demonstrate the offsets may not be in order
    srand(0);
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n_shards; ++i) {
        uint32_t j = rand() % n_shards;
        std::swap(offsets[i], offsets[j]);
        std::swap(sizes[i], sizes[j]);
    }

    uint32_t *nums_omp = new uint32_t[N];
    clock_t start = clock();
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(16)
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n_shards; ++i) {
        pread(fd, nums_omp + offsets[i], sizes[i] * sizeof(uint32_t),
              offsets[i] * sizeof(uint32_t));
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    printf("time: %fs\n", (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    close(fd);
}
```

The code tries to read from a file storing 400,000,000 consecutive integers. When using OpenMP the reading time is ~0.93s while normal reading is ~0.37s.

Could anyone tell me where is the problem?

---

**EDIT**

I’m using a NVMe SSD and the CPU and OS are i9-13900KF and Ubuntu 22.04. Still I don’t understand why omp has a much worse performance. Does switching threads has these high overheads? Also, if the file is larger (like TBs), will there be any difference?

Comment: Spinning up threads is cheap but not free. Racing 16 `pread` calls is also not guaranteed to improve throughput. You seem to be reading at 4GB/s already, which is a good fraction of what an NVMe SSD can do. Are you sure _this_ is what you need to speed up?

Comment: Ask yourself what is the main bottle neck when reading file? Then think if using threads can help with that? Threads are not a golden hammer of performance.

Comment: Please share the hardware information of the target machine. Especially the storage device (at least the kind : SSD or HDD), the CPU reference (e.g. "Intel i5-9600KF") and the OS/kernel version. This is critical for performance. So far, we do not even know the number of available cores (and it is not rare for people to use more threads than cores).

Comment: Multithreading doesn't work for file access. The disk can only go soo fast, so your threads just end up waiting for input and end up competing with each other as well. So loading the file is best done on one thread after that feel free to use threads for processing (but even that needs to be designed so you don't have to use locking too much and can make use of cache coherency). All in all threading is no free lunch

Comment: Also `uint32_t *offsets = new uint32_t[n_shards];` should be `std::vector<std::uint_32> offsets(n_shareds);` Current C++ hardly should have new/delete in it at all.

Comment: I think the main issue is that you use *[`clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock) which does* **not** *measure the wall clock time but the CPU (parallel) time*. `clock` is not even guaranteed to be monotonic. This is a very bad way to measure the timings. You should use [`omp_get_wtime`](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu160.html) for that.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I'v posted the hardware information in the edit

Comment: @JérômeRichard Okay it appears `clock` is the issue indeed. When I use `omp_get_wtime` or `clock_gettime`, both give me ~0.68s, which is an expected reading time.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Although plain `std::vector` can also be problematic in multi-threading due to NUMA with first-touch and `std::vector`'s initialization. People sometimes use custom allocators that implement the initialization as an empty member function to go around that.

Comment: @paleonix Fair enough. But memory allocation is done outside mutlthreading section in this code.

Comment: @PepijnKramer But that is exactly the critical case. The better argument would be that OP doesn't **initialize** the memory in parallel at the moment, so using `std::vector` would not be a pessimization as the first touch is done by a single thread on a single NUMA node either way.

Comment: If you want to time only the I/O's and not be (maybe) biased by the first touch of the `nums_omp` array, you should initialize the array (filling with zeros or whatever) before reading data into it.